# Add a schema in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

Can anybody tell me how I can add a schema/ schema location (XSD file) into XSLT1.0?

I don't have access to XSLT2.0, so I cannot use the `import-schema` function.

Here is my scenario:

I have an XSLT named myXSLT.xsl, then I have several Schemas say mSchema1.xsd, mSchema2.xsd and so on... it is in one location like http:\mylocation\schemas\

my problem is how can i link those schemas in my xslt so that when I create the XML, it can then be validated automatically, Im using vb.net and only available is the default engine MSXML? Or is that even possible or not?

Comment: What does "add a schema/schema location into XSLT1.0" mean?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Schema-aware XSLT processors are XSLT 2.0+ only; there is no XSLT 1.0 equivalent of `xsl:import-schema`.

If your use case is sufficiently restrictive, you might access some information from the XSD via `select="document('your.xsd')"`, but realize that you'll be on your own regarding XSD semantics -- this'll be solely  XML-level access.   See Tip: [How to combine documents with XSLT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipcombxslt/)